# CSS Grid auto spanning remaining blank columns

Tags: html, css

I'm searching for a solution to my problem with CSS grid.
The problem I have right now is I have a grid with 4 column and 10 boxes which fills a column row cell like so:
[image]
However, I would like the remaining two boxes to auto span to fit the entire width like this:
[image]
(box 9 and box 10).
Although I've achieved it here, I don't want to manually have to do it. I'd like the grid to automatically be able to do it. Is this achievable?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<style>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<style>

html {
   
}
.grid {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap:10px;
  
}
.grid .box {
   
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align: center;
  
    background-color: red;
   
}

/* .grid .box:nth-child(9) {
   grid-column: span 2;
}
.grid .box:nth-child(10) {
   grid-column: span 2;
} */
@media (max-width:768px){
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
}
</style>
<body>


    <div class="grid">

        <div class="box">Box 1</div>
        <div class="box">Box 2</div>
        <div class="box">Box 3</div>
        <div class="box">Box 4</div>
        <div class="box">Box 5</div>
        <div class="box">Box 6</div>
        <div class="box">Box 7</div>
        <div class="box">Box 8</div>
        <div class="box">Box 9</div>
        <div class="box">Box 10</div>
      
    </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS-Grid, you need flexbox.

Comment: Ah. Thanks very much.

Comment: What do you mean by `to auto span`? Your picture is possible with `grid`, just it's not clear what 'to auto span' is.

Comment: For box 9 and 10 in the first image, I would like that to evenly occupy the third row like the last picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with ***flex-box*** using ***flex-grow*** and a ***calc*** for the ***width***. For the *child* elements divisible by 4 the calc width will dynamically fill those in using the calculated width `width: calc(25% - 1em)`. For the left over elements *not divisible by four*, `flex-grow: 1` will ensure they fill up the remaining space.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1em;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: calc(25% - 1em);
  background-color: red;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Box 1</div>
  <div class="child">Box 2</div>
  <div class="child">Box 3</div>
  <div class="child">Box 4</div>
  <div class="child">Box 5</div>
  <div class="child">Box 6</div>
  <div class="child">Box 7</div>
  <div class="child">Box 8</div>
  <div class="child">Box 9</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Box 1</div>
  <div class="child">Box 2</div>
  <div class="child">Box 3</div>
  <div class="child">Box 4</div>
  <div class="child">Box 5</div>
  <div class="child">Box 6</div>
  <div class="child">Box 7</div>
  <div class="child">Box 8</div>
  <div class="child">Box 9</div>
  <div class="child">Box 10</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Box 1</div>
  <div class="child">Box 2</div>
  <div class="child">Box 3</div>
  <div class="child">Box 4</div>
  <div class="child">Box 5</div>
  <div class="child">Box 6</div>
  <div class="child">Box 7</div>
  <div class="child">Box 8</div>
  <div class="child">Box 9</div>
  <div class="child">Box 10</div>
  <div class="child">Box 11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome... Flex is more intuitively *flexible*, no pun intended, for dynamic layouts than grid.

Answer (score -2):

Actually you were very close:)

```css
.grid {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap:10px;
  
}
.grid .box {
   
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align: center;
  
    background-color: red;
   
}

.grid .box:nth-child(9) {
   grid-column: 1/span 2;
}
.grid .box:nth-child(10) {
   grid-column: 3/span 2;
} 
@media screen (max-width:768px){
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

        <div class="box">Box 1</div>
        <div class="box">Box 2</div>
        <div class="box">Box 3</div>
        <div class="box">Box 4</div>
        <div class="box">Box 5</div>
        <div class="box">Box 6</div>
        <div class="box">Box 7</div>
        <div class="box">Box 8</div>
        <div class="box">Box 9</div>
        <div class="box">Box 10</div>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: I already know how to do it manually, I wanted to know whether it was possible for CSS grid to be able to do it automatically.